# flask application with mysql tutorial

Tags: mysql, flask

In the [flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/setup/) at *Step 2: Application Setup Code*, I'd like to use mysql instead of sqlite3. Do I just do this:

```
# all the imports
import mysql
```

Comment: In case someone is still looking for a Flask tutorial with MySQL as database, this article may prove useful:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-flask-signing-in-and-out--net-29982

As a driver, pymysql can be use as it is pure python implementation and will run anywhere python will run.

Answer (score 7):

I would use Flask-SQLAlchemy then you can replace the tutorial code below:

```
# configuration
DATABASE = '/tmp/flaskr.db'
....
def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
```

with this

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://username:password@server/db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

You may find that learning SQLAchemy using [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/) with Flask will save you lots of time later on.

Comment: About Flask Sqlachemy; I read in the documentation that it's still being developed.

Comment: @MikeSila It is still being developed but it does not mean it cannot be used. In fact, as far as I know it does not limit you in using all the features of Sqlalchemy. It is basically a wrapper that does most of the boilerplate things to set up Sqlalchemy like removing a session after request.

Comment: *Everything* is still being developed if you think about it. Flask-SQLAlchemy is used in production for a number of apps...

Answer (score 4):

No, Python standard library does not include a MySQL connector. Install [pymysql](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/) and use that.

Incidentally, while progressing with the tutorial, you will understand the importance of having a ORM and you will find [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) more flexible than a direct MySQL connector. They used sqlite because it's a zero-effort solution, which is great for a quickstart tutorial: no separate database server to setup and manage.

Comment: About Flask Sqlachemy; I read in the documentation that it's still being developed and as far as databases are concerned I'd like to step into MySQl. I've looked around for a tutorial and all I'm seeing is sqlite3.

Comment: You can directly use SQLAlchemy, which is quite solid. Flask-MySQL bridge has been developed to ease the integration. Regarding tutorials, if you use pymsql, there are only few library functions to know, the rest is SQL language. If you still want to use MySQL, please **beware of SQL injections**.

Comment: Also Flask-Mysql http://flask-mysql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/  or can use oracles python mysql connector with flask. Flask-SQLalchemy is nice but a lot to learn if just starting out.

Comment: @Ixx: So you'd recommend Flask-MySQL as easier for a beginner to learn than Flask-SQLAlchemy?  What if the person knows Python well but knows nothing about SQL?